# Discord.py i would like to add the server icon next to the server name

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to add the server icon next to the server name but I don't know how I can send a image of what I'm talking about
[Image of what I would like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AwaM.png)
[Image of what I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIfGF.png)

My code:

```
@bot.command(name='mc', brief='Displays member count')
async def member_count(ctx):
  
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title=f"{ctx.guild.icon} {ctx.guild.name}",
        color=discord.Colour(int(0x7889da))
    )
    embed.add_field(name="Users", value=ctx.guild.member_count, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Humans", value=ctx.guild.member_count - len([m for m in ctx.guild.members if not m.bot]), inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Bots", value=len([m for m in ctx.guild.members if m.bot]), inline=True)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I tried adding the server icon in the title but it didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the title of the embed, simply use the [.set_author()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed.set_author) method. So your code would look like:

```py
@bot.command(name='mc', brief='Displays member count')
async def member_count(ctx):
  
    embed = discord.Embed(
        color=discord.Colour(int(0x7889da))
    )
    embed.add_field(name="Users", value=ctx.guild.member_count, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Humans", value=ctx.guild.member_count - len([m for m in ctx.guild.members if not m.bot]), inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Bots", value=len([m for m in ctx.guild.members if m.bot]), inline=True)
    embed.set_author(name=ctx.guild.name, icon_url=ctx.guild.icon.url)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```